# How do you keep the whitespace and formatting in a textarea form post?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to post a text area which I am storing into my database and I want to keep all of the white space so that I can query it out and display at a different place. The problem here is that when this form submits, the entire textarea is sent as a single line. I've looked into htmlspecialchar and urlencode but how can that be applied here if this is even the right place to use them?

```
<form name = "exam" action="takeTest.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="pa1" required rows=10 cols=55>public int add(int a, int b){






    }
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**EDIT**

Tried pre tags but those just show up as the default text in addition to the code. I think adding the \n tags will mess up the code when it's put through unit testing but I'm going to try it.

This part of my form is the programming part which is trying to emulate what codingbat is doing.

Comment: Each line will be seperated by `\n`, if that's what you mean?

Comment: This is actually taken from my php code and all of that is actually after $pageContent .= ' where I echo $pageContent later

Comment: Thank you for the link mario! Going to try wrapping in <pre></pre> tags

Answer (score 2):

Like @Danny said, the lines **are** separated, but not with the HTML line breaks, as you might expect.

To turn the newline characters (`\n`) into HTML line breaks (`<br>`), simply use [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php); so you can use your string from the database in a proper HTML.

It converts:

```
Hey\nthere
```

into:

```
Hey<br>there
```

which browsers render like:

```
Hey
there
```

Comment: I'm afraid it might mess with the unit testing since I am going to run the input after compiling it but I will give it a shot

Comment: That's how it's meant to be used. If you need to render HTML, use that function, if you need something else, make your own (probably using simple string replacing), but the bottomline is that the lines are there and you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Just read your update: no need to put any \n tags, like you said. They are there automatically. I'm saying that if you want to output this in HTML, just use `echo nl2br($your_text_var);`.

Answer (score 0):

before insert in db,  php has a function `nl2br()`.
then, if you'll echo the data on body just print else for editing this again in textarea use this

```
function br2nl($string)
{
    return preg_replace('/\<br(\s*)?\/?\>/i', "\n", $string);
}
```